# BCP not working when {CR} is missing & {LF} is present at the end of a fixed length file

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

```
SET @query='bcp Staging.DBO.MSP_Tin_Reference_Response_FileImport in '+@TinResponseFilePath+@TinResponseFileName+' -T -c ' 
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell @query --,1
```

And it throws following error:

```
NULL
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file
NULL
0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1     
NULL
```

I appreciate any help you could give me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-c` option by default requires that each line is terminated in `{CR}{LF}`. You can however tell BCP to use a different row terminator using the `-r` option.

I suggest you try the import with options `-c -r \n -t \t`. This specifies that the import will use the character data type for all fields, but specifies `{LF}` as the row terminator and TAB as the field separator.

Another thing is that it is best to always put your file name between double quotes (`"<file name>"`) otherwise the BCP command will fail if you have spaces in your file name.

So your command would look like this:

```
SET @query='bcp Staging.DBO.MSP_Tin_Reference_Response_FileImport in "'+@TinResponseFilePath+@TinResponseFileName+'" -T -c -r \n -t \t' 
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell @query --,1
```

---

Update: it looks like you're still experiencing problems; now BCP is asking for *file storage type of field XXX*.

You can solve this by:

1. First creating a format file for your table. You only need to do this once.
2. Specify the format file in your import command.

---

Step 1 (taking `C:\Temp\fi.fmt` as an example):

```
SET @query='BCP Staging.DBO.MSP_Tin_Reference_Response_FileImport format nul -f "C:\Temp\fi.fmt"';
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell @query;
```

---

Step 2. Run the import with the `-f` switch:

```
SET @query='bcp Staging.DBO.MSP_Tin_Reference_Response_FileImport in "'+@TinResponseFilePath+@TinResponseFileName+'" -f "C:\Temp\fi.fmt" -T -r \n -t \t' 
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell @query
```

Comment: Now it gives the following error:
NULL
Enter the file storage type of field ResponseData [varchar(max)]:

Comment: Weird, that's what the `-c` option is for, telling BCP to use character data. You could first create a format file for the `Staging.DBO.MSP_Tin_Reference_Response_FileImport` table by first running [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) with `BCP Staging.DBO.MSP_Tin_Reference_Response_FileImport format nul -f "<format_file>"`. Then specify the format file in your BCP import command using the `-f "format_file"` switch witthout the `-c` switch.

Comment: @Robin I've updated my answer with details on what I commented. HTH!

Comment: @Robin I'm happy to hear that =) GL!